# show multiple image based from push button

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make an application where in the application when we press a button, the button will display an image.

the design is like this:

[image: example]

in the image, when I press "Image A" then "Image A" will appear in the first space and so on as I pressed.
the question is, how? and what should I do? using graphicview (like in example) or using pixmap?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **QLabel** Object as the "Canvas" and use the `.setPixmap()` function on it.

For example:

```
self.myimage = QLabel(self)
self.myimage.setPixmap(QPixmap("C:\image_a.jpg"))
```

And later:

```
def change_image(self):
    self.myimage.setPixmap(QPixmap("C:\image_b.jpg"))
```